# astype() does not change floats

Tags: python, pandas

Even though this seems really simple, it drives me nuts. Why is .astype(int) not changing the floats to ints?  Thank you

```
df_new = pd.crosstab(df["date"], df["place"]).reset_index()
places = ['cityA', "cityB", "cityC"]
df_new[places] = df_new[places].fillna(0).astype(int)
sums = df_new.select_dtypes(pd.np.number).sum().rename('total')
df_new = df_new.append(sums)

print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
place      date          cityA    cityB       cityC
0       2008-01-01        0.0        0.0       51.0
1       2009-06-01        0.0      618.0        0.0
2       2015-07-01      549.0        0.0        0.0
3       2016-01-01       41.0        0.0        0.0
4       2016-04-01       62.0        0.0        0.0
5       2017-01-01      800.0        0.0        0.0
6       2018-07-01       69.0        0.0        0.0
total          NaT     1521.0      618.0       51.0
```

Comment: Try `df_new[places] = df_new[places].fillna(0, downcast='infer')`

Comment: doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

If there are NAs (which are floats in Pandas), the other values will be floats as well. See [here](http://%20http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na).